# shell script capture variable without formatting escape characters

Tags: shell, formatting, windows-subsystem-for-linux, backslash, unescapestring

I am running an .sh script from wsl bash.
Inside the script I want capture a file path, into a variable, in order to pass it to `cmd.exe` like so:

```bash
my_win_path=<some_windows_unc_path_to_executable>
cmd.exe /c "$my_win_path"
```

However when I try to capture the file path, it's backslashes are getting formatted, resulting in an non-valid path.

Example:

```bash
~: wslpath -w .
C:\tmp
~: var=$(wslpath -w .); echo $var
C:      mp
cmd.exe /c "$var # will error
```

How do I capture the output of `wslpath` into a valid variable without formatting the escape characters ?

(I hope I am using the right terminology here. Please correct me if not.)

Comment: Can you post error messages ?

Comment: I don't know what you want to achieve: Show the content of `var` using the command `echo -nE $var|xxd`, and explain which part of the content you want to remove.

Comment: @Philippe it probably would have been something like `... is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Comment: I must have gotten confused by the default `echo` output.

This actually worked fine:
```shell
~: wslpath -w ~/c/Python37/python.exe
C:\Python37\python.exe
~: python_exe=$(wslpath -w ~/c/Python37/python.exe);echo $var # or echo -nE $var
C:\Python37\python.exe
cmd.exe /c "$python_exe
```

Thanks @user1934428 , @Philippe

Comment: @sogrady : Don't put that much code in a comment. It's hard to read. Amend your question with properly formatted code.